# Errors showing while booting 16.04: "AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT..."

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 16.04, amd-processor

While this doesn't seem to affect performance or function in any ways, I get these errors when booting 16.04, but only when I have the proprietary Nvidia drivers installed (or possibly the AMD CPU microcode proprietary driver). The error is:

```
AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT device=02:00.0 domain=0x0011...
```

and then continues to show some additional numbers in sequence. See image below.

How can I make these messages go away during boot?

[image]

Running Ubuntu 16.04 x64 (Kernel 4.4.0-31-generic), Unity 7.4.0 desktop environment, AMD FX-8150 8x core CPU, 32GB RAM, 2x Nvidia GTX660 graphics cards, Nvidia 361.42 proprietary diver and microcode firmware for AMD CPU's from amd64-microcode proprietary driver.

Relevant portion of `lspci`:

```
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: [edit]ing and adding the kernel version, the output of `lspci` and the output of `sudo lshw -class display` might be helpful.

Comment: @ElderGeek:  Kernel 4.4.0-31-generic. Getting the rest now.

Comment: The section that matches your error is 02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. Now we should examine the output of `lsusb` to find the problematic device. Please [edit] the output into your question. Comments are far more limited in usefulness and longevity.

Comment: There may be an iommu kernel parameter you can pass that will resolve this but I am by no means an expert on that. Perhaps someone else can chime in on this

Comment: @Zanna suggested in the general chat room that you try the kernel parameter iommu=soft this may resolve your issue.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](//paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: @ElderGeek, that did it! Adding iommu=soft in grub.cfg made it go away. System even boots faster now. Thanks so much!

Comment: And @DavidFoerster, yes sir, I deleted the comments that listed all of the technical data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. edit the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` and add `iommu=soft` Resulting in something like

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet iommu=soft splash"
   ```

   if you haven't changed kernel parameters previously

The order of the parameters doesn't matter, the spaces between them are however important.

3. save the file
4. Issue the command `sudo update-grub`
5. Reboot

Props to @Zanna who confirmed the required kernel parameter in chat.

For a complete list of kernel parameters check https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

Comment: I only get this error if I leave my USB WLAN Adapter pluged in while booting. If I unplug my WLAN Adapter before booting everythings is fine. Later, after booting I can plug in my WLAN Adapter and everything still runs perfectly. (MB: Gigabyte AX370-Gaming K5 - bought 2017!)

Comment: @Peterling Did you attempt the answer above? What happened when you did?

Comment: This seemed to work for me. But I updated to a newer BIOS as well. So I cannot really tell what it was. Thanks anyway!