# Error booting Ubuntu or every distro I try

Tags: boot, usb

The only Linux distro I've been able to use was Zorin OS, but the iso I used had some other issues. Other than that, I've tried Ubuntu and Linux Mint and every time I boot from a live USB (install, or try without install) I get stuck here...

[image: error trying to boot ubuntu]

Comment: Please update and post your hardware specs. The last lines suggest an issue with Nvidia graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted [the answer from this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805008/errors-showing-while-booting-16-04-amd-vi-event-logged-io-page-fault) for the Ubuntu installer. It may get rid of the first error messages in your screenshot, which might in turn remove the later errors and allow you to boot.

1. Boot from your Ubuntu installer.
2. When you get to the GRUB boot menu, highlight "Try Ubuntu before installing" with the arrow keys and then press "e" to edit the boot entry.
3. Go to the line that begins with `linux` and add `iommu=soft` between `quiet` and `splash`, resulting in `quiet iommu=soft splash`
4. Press `Ctrl-X` or `F10` to boot.

Please note that you will need to do this every time you try to boot your installer. If you manage to get Ubuntu installed you can permanently fix this by following the instructions in the linked answer.

Comment: You're assuming the OP has hardware affect by the IOMMU issue and that has to be established prior to give any answer/suggestion. And I strongly recommend editing to remove the non-sense about the graphics cards.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Point taken. Please explain why it is nonsense to temporarily remove a device when it's driver produces these errors though. If Ubuntu boots with the card removed, would that not help to narrow down the source of the problem?

Comment: Granted, it's a valid troubleshooting path but in at end of the day OP will want to have his/her hardware working, including the graphics card. And knowing Nvidia cards DO work irrespective of the drivers requirements some may have, it's nonsense to include that in the answer, nonsensical and unhelpful actually. It could be a suggestion and as such fit for a comment but not the actual answer. Here we strive for high standards both at questions and answers.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Thank you, you are right, I edited the answer.