# IO_PAGE_FAULT when copying files between two HD

Tags: kernel, freeze, copy

I try to copy big amounts of data from one (spinning platter) disk to another (spinning platter) disk, but my computer always freezes after 1-4 hours with these messages in the system log:

```
Jan 24 20:52:02 user kernel: ahci 0000:01:00.1: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0001 address=0x40246e0000608040 flags=0x0030]
Jan 24 20:52:02 user kernel: ahci 0000:01:00.1: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0001 address=0x40246e0000608080 flags=0x0030]
Jan 24 20:52:02 user kernel: ahci 0000:01:00.1: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0001 address=0x40246e0000608024 flags=0x0030]
```

i tried to deactivate the IOMMU setting in the bios (which resulted in a pretty unusable network connection), and tried the answer to the question [Errors showing while booting 16.04: "AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805008/errors-showing-while-booting-16-04-amd-vi-event-logged-io-page-fault) , but it always happens. It does not matter if the second HD connected via external case or internal sata connection.

im running an up-to-date Ubuntu Mate 20.10.
how can i even find out what device is at fault? or what software? i am at a loss.

**Edit**: after a bios update ("50a" to "50e" so only a minor update) it seems to work now, although i don't know if it was the update or the settings reset that changed it. if the backup im running right now finishes i will close this question.

**Edit**: the BIOS update solved it.

Comment: IO Page Fault usually means bad memory. You can try and run the memtest from the live cd. You also have not said what version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output of `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema 
but i really doubt its a memory problem, i have a ressource monitor in the task bar.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**swap**

Your /swapfile (swap_1) is too small. Hence the IO_PAGE_FAULTs.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap

Note: locate and delete your swap_1 file (it may not be in /, as your line in /etc/fstab is incorrect)...
#sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 13G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

**Note: edit your existing swap_1 line in /etc/fstab to look like the following...**

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**memory**

13G RAM is an odd amount. Please edit your question and show me:

`sudo lshw -C memory`

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

A BIOS update from version "50a" to "50e" resolved the problem.