# Ubuntu PAGE_TAB_HARDWARE_ERROR boot error

Tags: boot, system-installation, 20.04, initramfs, amd-ryzen

Got new "Acer Swift 3" (SF314-41) laptop without OS and trying to install Ubuntu on it. Installed ubuntu-20.04.2-desktop-amd64 on USB drive with [rufus](https://rufus.ie/). On GNU GRUB chose Ubuntu and got next errors:\

```
[0.998986] iommu ivhd0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [PAGE_TAB_HARDWARE_ERROR device
...like 20 same errors with different timestamps
[1.001178] nvme 0000:0Z:00.0: AMV-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0
[1.299955] iommu ivhd0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [PAGE_TAB_HARDWARE_ERROR device
=03:00.3 pasid = 0x000b address=ox101b55cc000 flags=0x0208]
[8.367115] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.3: Error while assigning device slot ID
[8.367189] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.3: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[8.367252] usb usb2-port3: couldn't allocate usb_device
[8.367316] usb 1-4: hub fauled to enable device, error -62
[20.655135] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.3: Error while assigning device slot ID
[20.655210] xhci_hcd 0000:03:00.3: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 64.
[20.655271] usb usb1-port4: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

After a few seconds it restarts with acer + ubuntu load screen and again launches terminal with the next errors:

```
stdin: invalid argument
...like 50 same errors...
Unable to find a medium container a live system
Attempt interactive netboot from a URL ?
```

Tried to do as said in [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/810780/1181399) answer, but end up with

> sh: gksudo: not found

Also, as it is said in different sources, I tried all the USB ports and 2 different flash drives "SanDisk Ultra Fit 32GB USB 3.1" and "Intenso Alu Line 8GB USB Stick 2.0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of the iommu messages, you’ll need to add a kernel parameter to your Grub configuration. Here’s what you need to do:

1. Open a terminal, possibly from the Live USB if you’re unable to boot your system
2. Edit your Grub file:

   ```
   $ gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Add `iommu=soft` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. This will result in something like:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet iommu=soft splash"
   ```

   ***Note:** The order of the parameters is irrelevant.*
4. Save the file
5. Run `sudo update-grub`. This step is very important. Do not forget to run `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot the system

This should resolve your issue

Comment: How can I open a terminal from the Live USB ?

Comment: Use “Try Ubuntu”. That will boot into a live session. From there, open Terminal 

Comment: As it is said (the whole problem), I can't boot from this host. So to "Try Ubuntu" I used another laptop (where everything boots fine from this usb stick) and changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to "quiet iommu=soft splash" as you said (before was "quiet splash"). sudo update-grub was unsuccessful and ended with the next error: "/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get cannonical path of '/cow' ".

Comment: Ok, this is a partial solution for my problem. Before that, I did insert "iommu=soft" in GRUB menu. Here is the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315931/how-to-edit-etc-default-grub-on-live-usb/1316042#1316042